# CSS Floating box problem

Tags: css

Can someone please explain to me why these boxes are not lined up? 
http://seoplannow.com/comments.html
Thank you.

Comment: Please be more specific. Which boxes? How should they be aligned?

Comment: Remove the clear:both from subcontent fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `clear:both` from `subcontent`

Comment: No problem, glad you've fixed it. Remember to set the anwser as the accepted answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

If by "aligned" you mean one (#subcontent) beside the other (.wide_col) it's because you set clear:both; on each. Try to remove them and adjust the remaining CSS according to your needs.